# Why isn't "0" == "0"?

Tags: c++, winapi, stringstream

I do not have UNICODE in this project. This is a WinAPI project and the variable "input" is a stringstream with the default value "0". Why does the first id statement run and not 2nd one even though the string itself IS "0"?

```
void calc::AddToInput(int number)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, input.str().c_str(), "Input", NULL); //Shows "0"

    if(input.str().c_str() != "0") //Runs even though it shouldn't
    {
        input << number;
    }
    else if(input.str().c_str() == "0") //Doesn't run though it should
    {
        input.str("");
        input << number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bit misleading thing in [tag:c++] `std::string`, yes ;) ...

Comment: `input.str().c_str()` is UB, I believe

Comment: `input.str().c_str()` is not UB as long as the `char*` is only used while the `std::string` is still in scope.  It is not destructed until the entire statement that is using it is finished. Thus it is not UB in this example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Comparing C-style strings with `==` means "Do the first elements of these strings have the same address?". It doesn't actually compare the contents of the strings. For that, you need `strcmp`.

However, you have no reason to compare C-style strings - just use the `std::string` returned from `str()`, which can be compared using `==`, like so: `input.str() != "0"`.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the information. It works now. Our techer didn't inform us of that...

Comment: @TobiasSundell _Our techer didn't inform us of that..._ There's an implicit constructor from `const char*` to `std::string`, maybe you didn't notice the consequences when your teacher or your textbook informed you about **that**! ;) ...

Answer (score 5):

Because you're comparing pointers, not strings.  To compare strings either A) just compare the `std::string` instead of using `c_str()` (best), or B) use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer comparison. For raw `char*` comparison use `strcmp`. `strcmp` returns -1 or 1 if they're unequal, and 0 if they're equal.

Answer (score 3):

`input.str().c_str()`returns `const char*` which is simply a pointer value which actually is some adress like 0x1233abcd. "0" is also of type `const char*`, which is also a pointer and has some address ie. 0x6533ab3d. When you perform comparison like:

> if(input.str().c_str() != "0")

then its like comparing pointer values (addresses), so its like

> if ( 0x1233abcd != 0x6533ab3d )

you will get true all of the time

Answer (score 2):

As already was said in this if statement

```
if(input.str().c_str() != "0") //Runs even though it shouldn't
{
    input << number;
}
```

there is comparison of addresses of the first elements of string c_str() and string literal "0". As they have different addresses they are always unequal that is the condition is always true.

I think you meant

```
if(input.str().c_str()[0] != '\0') 
{
    input << number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you are comparing raw `char*` pointers, which have different addresses since they come from different sources.  To do what you are attempting, you need to use `std::string::operator==()` instead to compare the contents of the `std::string` rather than comparing pointers (and also, get rid of the redundant calls to `std:stringstream::str()`, all you are doing is wasting memory that way):

```
void calc::AddToInput(int number)
{
    std::string str = input.str();

    MessageBox(NULL, str.c_str(), "Input", NULL);

    if (str == "0")
        input.str("");

    input << number;
}
```

Or, if you get rid of the `MessageBox()` as well:

```
void calc::AddToInput(int number)
{
    if (input.str() == "0")
        input.str("");

    input << number;
}
```